# Accessing another page's functions in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Basically I have a page in my app where there's an async function that receives data via bluetooth. I want to execute functions on my main page based on the data I receive via bluetooth on the other page. I searched around a bit and mostly people suggest creating a base class and inheriting both pages from the same class, but that isn't what I'm trying to do: I don't want to execute a generic instance of the main page's function, I want to execute the specific main page function that belongs to the main page that my app is displaying.

I thought of two possible solutions to this:

1. Update a static variable in the main page class based on the received data, and use a property to execute the required functions every time the variable changes value, but the problem is that the functions I want to execute are non-static.
2. If I could know the object name of the main page class which my app instantiates, I could simply make the functions public and access them using syntax like *MainPageObjectName.myFunction()*, but I don't know the name of the object instantiated from the MainPage class by my app.

Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ali, I assume here that you need to update the contents of the MainPage.xaml while some background (async) task has finished.

The best way to do that is have a DataModel (MVVM) in your application. More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/gg521153%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj721615%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

By doing this when the async task finishes a function will be called to update the DataStructure that holds your data. Since that Model implements the INotifyPropertyChanged class the control on your UI (even though they are on another page) will be updated automatically.

Comment: Also even if you can get an instance of the `MainPage` class (eg, by stashing it in a global static) you can't guarantee it will always be there in the case of tombstoning (suspend/terminate/resume).